# Function for getting absolute value doesnt work on decimals

Tags: c#, math

I am trying to make a method that returns Frobenius Norm.

```
    public static decimal FNorm2(decimal[,] mat)
    {
        decimal ats = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < mat.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < mat.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                ats += Math.Pow(Math.Abs(mat[i, j]), 2);
            }
        }
        Math.Pow(ats, 0.5);
        return ats;
    }
```

This is my code.

And I get:

Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'decimal' to 'double'
on line

```
    ats += Math.Pow(Math.Abs(mat[i, j]), 2);
```

it redlights the Math.Abs function.

Comment: No, it's actually that `Math.Pow` doesn't support `decimal`. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pow?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: `decimal` is not a suitable return type for this method. You should use `double` instead.

Comment: [`Abs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.abs?view=netframework-4.8#System_Math_Abs_System_Decimal_) is fine; it is `Pow` that it tripping you up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Math.Pow` takes double parameters and additionally, you'll need to store its result. You can either declare `ats` as a double or use a library handling Pow on decimals (like [this one](https://www.extremeoptimization.com/Documentation/Reference/Extreme.Mathematics.DecimalMath.Pow.aspx) for instance).

```
double ats = 0;
...
double result = Math.Pow(ats, 0.5);
return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an absolute value when you square a number; squares are always positive.

`Math.Pow` is inefficient for squaring values.  What's wrong with `x*x`?

I'd use a square root function.

```
public static double FNorm2(double[,] mat)
{
    double ats = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < mat.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            ats += mat[i, j]*mat[i, j];
        }
    }
    return Math.Sqrt(ats);
}
```

Comment: that's right, if the 2.0 is really fixed for eternity and never turns 2.5 or 3.0
For your sample, you should create a local variable for the mat-value, to avoid computing indexes and accessing the array twice. That's the downgrade of this approach.
But it may be the compiler is taking care of everything and does all these optimizations by itself (Replacing Pow(x,2) with x*x); I know it does x*2 replace with xx << 1.
So there are so many assumptions, you cannot say you turn something better or worse with a change, since the compiler tries to be 'intelligent' also.

Comment: This is a Euclidean norm - it's been a power of two since Euclid's time.  I feel confident we're on solid ground here.  I've done scientific computing as a career.  I can say this is better.

Comment: I take your '2' for serious. The rest "It's true because I know" it's not. That's a matter of compilation, not 'scientific computing'. "I'm an authority" is really funny. Once we go into the disassembly, we could check; but's it's not worth doing it.

Comment: I suggested you put it in a local variable `var x = mat[i;j]; ats+=x*x` your answer was "I feel confident, your way is better" without giving any reason or justification: Further-on you said: the compiler is not converting a Call to pow(x, 2) to x*x by itself, without any explanatory statement. You spread assumptions.
'Better' is an undefined word, you can be better in performance, better in 'code structure' better in human readability. I talk in matter of performance. Don't get rude please. We are professionals, one as good as the other.